# Is there a phrase meaning that we do not want to talk about something regrettable that we wish to forget?

Tags: phrase-requests

In italian we say:

> stendiamo un velo pietoso

when do not want to talk about something regrettable or embarrassing that we wish to forget.

How can I translate it in english?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the equivalent English expression ***[draw a veil over sth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/draw-a-veil-over-sth)​:***

> - If you draw a veil over a particular subject, you do not speak about it because it is unpleasant and you do not want to think about it:
>
>   - *Yes, well I think we'll just draw a veil over what went on last night.*

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

There are psychology terms **suppression** and **repression**.

*Suppression* means to redirect one's thoughts away from a psychologically negative stimulus. When a better time comes, the thought recurs and is worked through. It is considered psychologically healthy, a positive coping skill.

*On the contrary, *repression* occurs when the unwanted thought is buried deep within one's psyche. There is no intent to further process, and layers of protection, usually unhealthy--like drugs and alcohol, insulate the psyche from the unwanted thought. When repression is used to cope, the negative psychological energy created often comes out in other ways, say anger control problems. This is considered an unhealthy coping response.

*The waiter suppressed his awful day at work, dropping 2 armloads of dishes, until after he slept. Awaking, he realized the patrons clapping were trying to lighten the mood rather than make fun of him.*

*The waiter had an awful day, having dropped two armloads of dishes. He immediately went to the bar and repressed the memories of the laughing customers. Two weeks later he quit his job.*